# Adding input fields together and displaying in a label

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm writing a program to add tests, exams, practicals, assignments to  a module.

With regards to the course weighting I was wondering if you could dynamically change the value of the total weighting when a user enters a weighting per task.

Like this:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd0wK.png)

The inputs in the red rectangle should be added up and displayed in the blue rectangles label.
In turn, the blue rectangle should be added up and displayed in the green rectangles label.

Any help will be appreciated please

I have tried this so far:

```
<form name="Calcultor" Method="Get" id='form1'>First Number:
<input type="text" name="fnum" size="35" id="first">
+ Second Number:
<input type="text" name="snum" size="35" id="sec">
+ Third Number:
<input type="text" name="lom" size="35" id="third3">
<br>
<br>Answer:
<input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
<button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
```

```
<script lang="javascript">
function Calculate() {
    var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    if(document.getElementById('sec'))
    {
        var last = document.getElementById('sec').value; 
    }
    else
    {
        var last = 0; 
    }
    if(document.getElementById('third'))
    {
        var third = document.getElementById('third').value; 
    }
    else
    {
        var third = 0; 
    }        
    document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(last) + parseInt(third);
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/www1fxjb/9/

What I am asking is to change the label as soon as the numbers change in the input fields.

Comment: what have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I will upload what i have tried in a moment. What I'm asking is to update the label when i change text instead of pushing a calculate button

Comment: @user2366842 updated

Comment: Good update to your question. Can you explain what the `Calculate()` function isn't doing that you expect it should be doing? Or what error it's giving?

Comment: @PaulHicks Thank you, the function works fine if I click the button but i want the calculate function to be called when the user changes the number in input 1, 2 or 3 instead of clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `onchange`event in your input fields properties.

You can then point your `onchange`event to your calculate method.

Also, add default values of "0" in your input fields so that it will always have a value to add and this will prevent errors.

```
<input type="number" name="fnum" size="35" id="first" onchange="Calculate();" value="0"/>
+ Second Number:
<input type="number" name="snum" size="35" id="second" onchange="Calculate();" value="0"/>
+ Third Number:
<input type="number" name="lom" size="35" id="third" onchange="Calculate();" value="0"/>
<br />
Answer:
<input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script lang="javascript">
    function Calculate() {
        if (document.getElementById('first')) {
            var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
        }
        else {
            var first = 0;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('second'))
        {
            var second = document.getElementById('second').value; 
        }
        else
        {
            var second = 0; 
        }
        if (document.getElementById('third'))
        {
            var third = document.getElementById('third').value; 
        }
        else
        {
            var third = 0; 
        }        
        document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second) + parseInt(third);
        document.form1.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps.